# Visual Studio Android Emulator has no internet access

Tags: visual-studio-emulator

I am trying to use the Visual Studio Android Emulator without success.

I have updated to latest version of Windows 10 (pro) 1511.

Here's what I did to install the Emulator

- uninstalled genymotion and VirtualBox.
- removed any previously created hyper-v adapters from the device manager
- turned on Hyper-v from Windows features and restarted
- installed Visual Studio Emulator
- tried to create a profile and start the Emulator

I have only a WiFi adapter. In my network connections I can see the following

- WiFi bridged
- Ethernet 3, connected (Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver)
- vEthernet Wireless Virtual Switch. This one uses the actual WiFi adapter.

IPv4 169.254.37.65
Mask 255.255.0.0

- vEthernet (Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)

IPv4 169.254.80.80
Mask 255.255.0.0

My network gateway is at 192.168.1.1 and gives addresses from 1.2 up to 1.100

The host machine and the Emulator  have no internet access.

Any ideas / help would be really appreciated.

Thanks